# Create a base template for all future helm charts

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'd like to create a base template for all future helm charts that I need to configure.

Looks possible this approach but I'm a little bit worried about the labels self managed by chart and for some reason tiller lose the control of the chart like the example below.

```
metadata:                                                                                                                                                       name: {{ include "standard.fullname" . }}                                                                                                                     labels:                                                                                                                                                  
    app: {{ include "standard.name" . }}                                                                                                                      
    chart: {{ include "standard.chart" . }}                                                                                                                   
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}                                                                                                                              
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
```

So since I know my whole environment looks possible create one unique helm chart for all the cases with some boolean flags to enable or disable some content, the main question is, is there any problem to change the default values from the labels and move them to the values.yaml?